# SSRS Matrix table report. Merge rows

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

This is how I'm getting the table.

```
+------+---------+-----------+---------+
| Cstmr| morning | afternoon |  night  |
+------+---------+-----------+---------+
| ab   | N/A     | N/A       |    car  |
|      | N/A     | N/A       |    11pm |
|      | bike    | N/A       |    N/A  |
|      | 9am     | N/A       |    N/A  |
|      | N/A     | cycle     |    N/A  |
|      | N/A     | 2pm       |    N/A  |
| ac   | N/A     | N/A       |    car  |
|      | N/A     | N/A       |    11pm |
|      | bike    | N/A       |    N/A  |
|      | 9am     | N/A       |    N/A  |
+------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

I want it to be displayed like this.

```
+------+---------+-----------+---------+
| Cstmr| morning | afternoon |  night  |
+------+---------+-----------+---------+
| ab   | bike    | cycle     |    car  |
|      | 9am     | 2pm       |    11pm |
| ac   | bike    | N/A       |    car  |
|      | 9am     |           |    11pm |
+------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Cstmr is Customer. morning: 6am-12pm. afternoon: 12pm-10pm. night: 10pm-6am. For customer 'ab', bike is provided at 9am, cycle at 2pm, car at 11pm. According to the time data should be displayed in respective columns. It should display N/A if no vehicle is provided in that time.

[And this is how parent and child groups are formed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wJbx.jpg)

Comment: Nice question.  Now just tell us how the various values are related to each other and maybe you will get an answer.

Comment: Cstmr is Customer. morning: 6am-12pm. afternoon: 12pm-10pm. night: 10pm-6am. For customer 'ab', bike is provided at 9am, cycle at 2pm, car at 11pm. According to the time data should be displayed in respective columns. It should display N/A if no vehicle is provided in that time.

Comment: I forgot to notice "SSRS".In report my approach may be different,becasue we hv formula option over there.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO,how come it is good question from project point of view ?When data are not normalize at all.

Secondly what is the meaning of "This is how I'm getting the table."
This is how the actual table is or this the resultset you get after some query.

Thirdly,try this script with other sample data and tell me what is the issue.
If above script is correct but slow then we can apply paging for any biz requirement.

```
declare @t table(Cstmr varchar(20),morning varchar(20)
,afternoon varchar(20), night varchar(20))

insert into @t VALUES
('ab','NA','NA','car')
,( null, 'NA','NA','11pm ')
,( null, 'bike','NA','NA  ')
,( null, '9am','NA','NA  ')
,( null, 'NA','cycle','NA  ')
,( null, 'NA','2pm','NA  ')
,('ac','NA','NA','car  ')
,( null,'NA','NA','11pm ')
,( null,'bike','NA','NA  ')
,( null,'9am','NA','NA  ')

;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT Cstmr
        ,morning
        ,afternoon
        ,night
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) rn
    FROM @t
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT cstmr
        ,morning
        ,afternoon
        ,night
        ,rn
        ,CASE 
            WHEN morning = 'NA'
                THEN 0
            WHEN isdate(morning) = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 2
            END rnm
        ,CASE 
            WHEN afternoon = 'NA'
                THEN 0
            WHEN isdate(afternoon) = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 2
            END rnaf
        ,CASE 
            WHEN night = 'NA'
                THEN 0
            WHEN isdate(night) = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 2
            END rnn
    FROM cte c
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN c.cstmr IS NULL
                THEN c1.cstmr
            ELSE c.cstmr
            END
        ,c.morning
        ,c.afternoon
        ,c.night
        ,c.rn
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.morning = 'NA'
                THEN 0
            WHEN isdate(c.morning) = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 2
            END rnm
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.afternoon = 'NA'
                THEN 0
            WHEN isdate(c.afternoon) = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 2
            END rnaf
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.night = 'NA'
                THEN 0
            WHEN isdate(c.night) = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 2
            END rnn
    FROM cte c
    INNER JOIN cte1 c1 ON c.rn = c1.rn + 1
    )
SELECT m.Cstmr
    ,m.morning
    ,m.rnm
    ,a.afternoon
    ,n.night
FROM cte1 m
LEFT JOIN cte1 a ON a.cstmr = m.cstmr
    AND m.rnm = a.rnaf
LEFT JOIN cte1 n ON n.cstmr = m.cstmr
    AND m.rnm = n.rnn
WHERE m.morning <> 'NA'
```